# JDialog Mouse Listener called as not expected

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

In my swing application, I have used JDialog and added a JPanel to the JDialog. I want the mouse listener of JDialog called when the mouse exits the JDialog. Here is how I did it.

```
myJDialog.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {  
    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {  
        System.out.println("Mouse has exited the Dialog");  
    }  
});
```

Actually it is called when the mouse exits, but when the mouse goes into a JTextField which is in the Jpanel that added to JDialog, this listener is called as the mouse exited even though the mouse is still inside the JDialog.  I want to get the listener called when completely the mouse exited and not called when the mouse goes to its child component which is in itself. How can I solve this?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481804/capture-trap-the-mouse-cursor-in-a-window-in-java might lead you to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an easy question to answer.

Lets start with the mouseListener.  Try and think of your container (in this case the dialog) as a 3D plan, on top of that plan, we add components.  Each component exists on one or more layers above the container (casting a nice shadow).

Now, think of the mouse as a laser pointing down onto the top of that plan.  So long as the laser light can reach your container, you will receive notification about mouse events.  However, if the mouse is moved so that another component blocks it (the laser can no longer reach your component), you stop receiving notification, as the the events are blocked.

Now, the notification system is kind enough to let you know when the mouse enters and exists you domain of influence.

This is how the system works.  Other then using a Global Event Handler (which will at least let you know where the mouse context has moved to), the only "other" solution I can think of is to check the coordinates of the mouse exit event and check them against your content pane's bounds.

```
public void mouseExit(MouseEvent evt) {
    Point p = evt.getPoint();
    Rectangle bounds = getBounds();

    bounds.x += 4;
    bounds.y += 4;
    bounds.width -= 4;
    bounds.height -= 4;

   if ((p.x < bounds.x || p.x > bounds.x + bounds.width) && (p.y < bounds.y || p.y > bounds.y + bounds.height) {

       System.out.println("Elvis has left the building");

   }

}
```

This of course is probably going to need some tweaking in order to get just right.

Comment: What are the `+= 4` and `-= 4` ?

Comment: The purpose of te +/- 4 is simply a margin of error (which needs to be tested & refind). If a mouse moves fast enough, it's possible you won't quite get the exact edge of the component, but the last recorded position

Comment: Thanks M Programmer. The way you handled it was my current approach to solve it. I was looking for another better listener. It sounds that, no such listener to help :( . Thank u once again.

Comment: No problems, and I feel your pain